# Reserved Characters in URI

Tags: cross-browser, uri

Is a URI written like Method 1 likely to cause problems on certain browsers vs Method 2? If so, on which ones? Can someone point to a source?

Method 1
    test.dev/mypage?attributes[]=1&attributes[]=2&attributes[]=3

Method 2
    test.dev/mypage?attributes%5B%5D=1&attributes%5B%5D=2&attributes%5B%5D=3

Comment: Searching for "uri" in your favorite search engine should have provided links to RFC/Wikipedia, but probably one you like just does not work. Here is link: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the W3C's specification of URIs:
https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/uri-spec.html

None of those characters `[]=&` are listed as reserved or unsafe, so either method should be fine.